# Open Android Native Player from Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-video-player

I'm trying to open a video in android player from fragment but send me this error

No Activity found to handle Intent

here's the code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.learn, container, false);
    ImageButton mBtn =  (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.iBtn1);
    mBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getActivity().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video_1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, video);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
return rootView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how im using it:

```
 public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    //Creating MediaController
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String path = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.EXTRA_VIDEO_PATH);
    //specify the location of media file

    //File imageFileFolder = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), Constants.APP_FOLDER);
    //imageFileFolder.mkdir();
    //        File photoFile = new File(imageFileFolder,
    //                path);
    File photoFile = new File(
            path);
    Uri uri=Uri.fromFile(photoFile);

    //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();




}
```

I think its not possible with intent to do what you asking for.

Comment: i added my implement, please try using it.